# Maven read .env file and set environment vars

Tags: maven

I've got a .env file that has stuff like:

`SOME_PROPERTY_I_NEED_IN_MY_UNIT_TESTS=xyz`

I need Maven to load this .env file and export all vars in it as env vars for my tests.

This needs to be a file defined on the filesystem (in `/tmp/.env`, say) and not in the classpath.

I also need it loaded via maven since this is only for unit testing (actually running the code will get env vars from elsewhere, and not load a `.env` file).

How do I do this?

Comment: What are "env vars" ? Are you referring to values you can fetch using System.getEnv() ?

Comment: I need to load a file and propagate the contents to environment variables (just like doing `export SOME_PROPERTY_I_NEED_IN_MY_UNIT_TESTS=xyz` - I guess the answer is yes to your second question.

Comment: That seems more the job of a shell script, not Maven.

Comment: Why do you need them for tests? That means all you testcode is environment variable dependent?

Comment: That is correct. I'm not sure how else I'd pass secrets to unit/integration tests? I can't very well commit secrets to my source control. The standard way of doing things that I'm aware of is to use environment variables to separate the credentials from the code.

Comment: If you need secrets in your tests that means you are doing integration tests instead of unit tests. The question is do you really need real secrets? Are those tests correct and needed secrets to test what you are testing...

Comment: @khmarbaise - OK, so it's integration testing and not unit testing. The answer is yes, I really need real secrets. The entire point of the tests depends on the secrets, and yes, it's what I want to test. What does that have to do with the environment vars?

Comment: You can simply define them via `mvn -Dxyz=abc verify` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise - You should re-read the question and you'll see that you are not answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Properties Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/)

Below is this section of my pom file where I implemented this. I have it reading `.env` and my `application.properties` file.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <useDefaultValues>true</useDefaultValues>
              <files>
                <file>${project.basedir}/.env</file>
                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

If you're running `mvn test`, I think that should do what you expect.

For my initial use case I needed to get some values to the maven flyway plugin. That required including the `initialize` phase: `mvn initialize flyway:info`

Secondly, I wanted to use the env values in my `application.properties` file. This allows for that. So if `.env` has

```
DB_USERNAME=user
```

then `application.properties` can have

```
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.flyway.user=${DB_MAINTENANCE_USERNAME:${DB_USERNAME}}
```

Note that setting `useDefaultValues` to `true` allows for having fallback values like I have for `spring.flyway.user`. Otherwise, that option is not needed.